# node doesn't work on mac

Tags: node.js, macos

I just installed node.js using the package installer from their website, and I can't use the "node" command or "npm" from terminal. usr/local/bin is in my $PATH but I don't have permissions to navigate there. Doing sudo cd bin doesn't even work. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found it out. I didn't have read permissions and that was blocking it so I just had to run a chmod -r to get it working. thanks!